# Convert DC 1.5V to 2.7V

Tags: dc

How can I convert DC 1. 5V (R20 cell) to DC 2.6V with as much as possible amps?

I would like to charge 500F supercapacitor with it. (I can use only 1 R20 1.5V cell).

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/18570/2028

Answer (score 7):

You need a [DC-DC Boost Converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter). You won't be able to get more power than the cell can provide—in fact, you'll get *less* due to efficiency losses in the boost converter. Since you're boosting the voltage, you have to settle for less amperage.

[$$P = IE$$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)

So if your R20 1.5V cell can sustain 2A, that provides for a load of 1.5 * 2 = 3W.

If you use a boost converter with 90% efficiency, you would get 2.7W out of it. Calculating for 2.6V (I = W/E) shows that the current would then be ~1.04A.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that OP said he's charging a supercapacitor. If there is a particular frequency OP needs to charge the capacitor in, he'll have to take that into account when designing a boost converter